# Calculate age from birthdate in psql in Intellij Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I use Intellij with Spring Boot. In my PSQL Database I have a column named as dob (date of birth) and I want with a @Query annotation extract the person's age from the birthdate and get all the male persons that have age over 60. I have tried to do it but with no result. Do you have any suggestions?

```
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findByUsername(String username);

    @Query("select new com.example.personservice.dto.MalesCovidOverSixty(p.gender,count(p.gender)) " +
            "from Person p " +
            "where p.gender='Male' " +
            "and p.covid='t' " +
            "and age(p.dob,current_date)>'20' " +
            "group by p.gender " +
            "order by count(p.gender) desc")
    List<MalesCovidOverSixty>findMalesCovidOverSixty();
    }
```

In Postman it gives me empty brancets [].
In Person.class dob is set as LocalDate.
I have a male person in my database who is over 20 so I tried this for beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer! I post it just in case someone else has the same problem.

```
"and extract(year from(age(current_date, p.dob)))>'60' " +
```